# Find all patterns matching regular expression using the Kate editor

Tags: regex, find, substring, findall, kate

I frequently use the Kate editor. It is possible to find patterns using regular expressions in Kate. For example the expression `\d{3}` will find all occurrences of 3 consecutive digits in the following text:

```
asdfsdf 234 dffd 234 f
d 182 sdsdas 182 sfdds
fdsfk 324 d 890 dfsdfd
```

Is it possible to extract the matching strings somehow? Or simply said: How do I get the following numbers only by using Kate? Is that possible in a simple way or possibly with a plugin? I know that I could for example use pythons `re.findall()` method but this is not what I want.

```
234
234
182
182
324
890
```

Comment: Replace `\d{3}` with `$0\n` and then `(\d{3})|.` with `$1`

Comment: This gives me many lines like $1$1$1$1$1$1 do I miss something?

Comment: Maybe the backreferences are written as `\1`?

Comment: Ok you are right. This works, thank you! Can you explain to me the second replacement? What does |. do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My 2-stepapproach consists in 2 steps:

- Add a newline after 3 digits with `(\d{3})` --> `\1\n` replacement (where `\1` refers to the captured value) and then
- Remove any character that is not a starting point for three digits and reinserting 3 digits captured with a capturing group with `(\d{3})|.` --> `\1` replacement.

The `(\d{3})|.` pattern matches and captures 3 digits OR just matches any character other than a newline, and `\1` is a backreference to the value captured with `(\d{3})`.

There may appear some  empty lines, but they can usually be removed with built-in features.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I updated your post since it is \1 in kate and not \0.